# Saving and Loading a large dictionary using python pickle

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle, large-data

I have a dictionary, it's size is 5300 keys. I want to save that dictionary using `pickle.dump`:

```
with open("file.txt", "wb") as f:
        data.dump(result, f)
```

and load using `pickle.load`:

```
with open(path+"file.txt","rb") as f:
        data = pickle.load(f)
```

But there is a `memory error` because the size of the dictionary. I'm using Windows with 4GB RAM and Python 2.7.
I dont know how to fix this, is there an alternative way to handle a large dictionary pickle?

thank you for your advice...

Comment: 5300 keys is hardly large. You should be able to use that directly with no issues. How large are your *values*? Also, you could use the `shelve` library; this uses pickle to store values still, but does so *per key*, and transparently.

Comment: what is also your version of python: 32 bits, 64 bits?

Comment: @MartijnPieters there are also 5300 values in that dictionary. Is `shelve` library still can solve this?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I use python for 32 bits

Comment: @estu: of course there are, that's the definition of a dictionary. How *big* are those values? 5300 references to `None` take up hardly any memory, for example.

Comment: @estu: and yes, shelve can handle that **just fine**. You can use *millions* of keys.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i try  `shelve` library using this code ` with shelve.open("model.txt", 'c') as shelf:
        shelf['dict'] = result
        shelve.close()` but there's an error `AttributeError: DbfilenameShelf instance has no attribute '__exit__'`

Comment: @estu: `shelve` objects are not context managers. Just use `some_variable = shelve.open(...)`, and use that `some_variable` as a dictionary throughout your code.